# Assigning first row from a generic list to an Object

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a `Generic List<SomeCode>` list containing multiple values.

I am trying to pass the first row in the list to an object as:

```
if(list.count==1)
    SomeCode sc = list[0];
```

Can you please tell me why is this happening?

Here is my Class

```
public class SomeCode
{
    private int _Somecodeid;
    private string _Somecodeescription;
    private string _Somecode;

    public int SomeCodeId
    {
        get { return _Somecodeid; }
        set { _Somecodeid = value; }
    }

    public string SomeCodeDescription
    {
        get { return _Somecodeescription; }
        set { _Somecodeescription = value; }
    }

    public string Code
    {
        get { return _Somecode; }
        set { _Somecode = value; }
    }
}
```

I populate a list LIST list.
The method Contains an object 
SomeCode sc = new SomeCode

Now when I Assign the very first row to the object as

```
if(list.count==1)
    SomeCode sc = list[0];
```

Then all the values get assigned except Code.

It takes all the items in the list except the first one. The first item gets printed like this:

```
"sc.SomeCode= SomeCode"s
```

however other values are added properly 
sc.SomeCodeDescription = "Hello"; etc

When I explicitly assign the values, then it works:

```
sc.firstItem = list[0].firstItem
```

Comment: Please show a proper example.

Comment: if firstItem is a SomeCode object, why are you assigning it the class name?

Comment: I am not assigning it the class name, I assign the entire row. But for somereason , the first Item is not properly added to the object and when I try to print it, it prints the class name instead

Answer (score 1):

Try overloading the "=" operator and assign the matching values.
Something like this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your target Framework is 3.5 or higher I think what you are looking for could be provided using LINQ. Keep in mind you will have to Import System.Linq;  Try something like this,

```
if(list.count==1)
  SomeCode sc = list.First();
```